# Why does the overload resolution of member functions exclude the global functions?

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, overloading, overload-resolution

```
void f()
{}

struct A
{
    void f()
    {}
};

struct B : A
{
    B()
    {
        f(); // A::f() is always called, and ::f is always ignored 
    }
};

int main()
{
    B();
}
```

As the class `B`'s designer, I MIGHT NOT know the fact that `B`'s base class, i.e. `A`, has a member function `A::f`, I just know `::f`, and call `::f` is just what I want.

What I expects is the compiler gives an error because of ambiguity of calling `f`. However, the compiler always chooses `A::f` and ignore `::f`. I think this might be a big pitfall.

I just wonder:

**Why does the overload resolution of member functions exclude the global functions?**

**What's the rationale?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As the class B's designer, I MIGHT NOT know B's base class

I don't agree.

> Why does the overload resolution of member functions exclude the
>   global functions?

Because the two overloads belong to two different scopes and compiler chooses the overload of same scope. Reading §3.4.1 . The `f` of inner (same) scope hide the outside's `f`.

> What's the rationale?

To have a solid rule. We prefer to work in a same scope. Unless we explicitly want to call an object from somewhere else.

In a family by calling Alex, they expect their little boy Alex comes in, not the [Alexander III of Macedon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_the_Great).

Answer (score 4):

That's just how overload resolution works, and **it's good**.

Imagine you really have a big project, tons of inter-dependencies, third party code and cross-module includes. In this huge mess, you have that one class you know works. It has been working perfectly for 5 years, it's efficient, easy to read and clean. You don't want to touch it. You then upgrade a modules, and start getting compiler errors. Oh no! That module (which you have no control over) introduced a new function `DoAmazingStuff()` at the global namespace. The same as a method name in our class. You're going to have to refactor it, since now you can no longer use the same name for a class member. Bummer!

Comment: It's worth adding your argument still applies even if the two `f`s have different type signatures - because the class may be relying on casting the arguments to `f`.